# Centering the contents of a <div>

Tags: html, center

I have searched and searched, but I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem. I am trying to center the contents of a `<div>` tag within the body of my document. It is a mobile site, so the margins on the left and right will have to be equal on a variety of different viewports and devices.

This is the div that I am trying to center:

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="http://m.usci.westondev.com/healthcare-certificates-2/">Healthcare/a
<a href="http://m.usci.westondev.com/business-certificates-2/">Business</a><br />
<a href="http://m.usci.westondev.com/wellness-certificates-2/">Wellness</a><br />
<a href="http://m.usci.westondev.com/technology-certificates/">Technology</a><br />
<a href="http://m.usci.westondev.com/legal-certificates/">Legal</a><br />
<a href="http://m.usci.westondev.com/services-certificates-2/">Services</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS that I thought would work is simply:

```
#nav {
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
display:block;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
}
```

However, this is not doing the trick. This div is nested inside a number of other `<div>` tags, and I have tried applying the `{margin-right:auto, margin-left:auto}` to all of them, but nothing seems to be working.

There must be something that I am missing, but I am out of ideas.

The page I am working on is at:
http://m.usci.westondev.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give the div you are trying to center a width. All of your parent divs have width 100%, so this one will as well.

Auto works by margining left and right any LEFTOVER space that your width does not take up. So if you give your nav a width = to its contents, it will center properly.

Comment: Hmmmmm...very interesting. I gave the css class above a width like you said and now it is centering properly, but only on my desktop monitor. It still is not centering on my Iphone.

Comment: you click on the up arrows next to answers to vote them up. if you want to accept an answer as THE answer to your question, you click the faded checkbox just below that

Comment: Looks like I can't do that yet. I need a reputation of 15.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool like Chrome Developer Tools to debug.  You'll see that your A tags are taking the full width of the containing div.  Setting a width to them should fix:

```
#page-container .page .content #nav a:link {width: 280px;}
```

Comment: I'm using Firebug. It's worked well for me, but this time I am stumped. :)

Comment: Looks like you're almost there. I see you added the `width:290px;` value to the #nav a:link css. Adjust that width to the width of 279px, which is width of your background image (304px) minus your padding (25px) on that A tag.